# Mouse middle click in Mac OS — Misson Control and Close Tab at the same time: How To?

Tags: macos, mouse

How to make wheel mouse button work this way in Mac OS X El Capitan?

```
1. If I wheel press on chrome tab, this tab gets closed.
else: 2. If I press on chrome link, it gets opened in new tab.
else: launch mission control.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one program that I have found that does this really well:  [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/)

Technically, it's very much overkill in comparison to what you need and what is provided by the commonly known apps like Karabiner, BetterTouchTool and Keyboard Maestro.

With ControllerMate, you can create a a sequence of events depending on what button is pressed with whatever modifier in whatever application you specify.

For example, I created a sample workflow that checks to see if the middle button of the mouse is pressed and if the mouse is on a Chrome Tab (this will have to be written outside this example), it will issue the <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> (Close) keyboard shortcut.

[image]

If you notice, I have this setup specifically for the "Chrome Group."  With this setting, you can create a "programming page" that is only active when you specify:

[image]

Bottom line:  this can be done, with a little Apple Script programming (so that you can detect when your Chrome Tab is in Focus) or when you are on a URL.