# Is it possible to bind mouse 4 btn to a specific key on the keyboard on MacOS?

Tags: keyboard, macos, mouse

I bought a cheap USB mouse with 2 additional buttons, the ones that you can click to go back and forward when surfing etc.

**I'm wondering if it's possible to bind one of those mouse buttons to another key on the keyboard?**

Scenario:
I press mouse 4, and it clicks on number 1 on the keyboard.

I'm on MacOS Sierra.

Comment: There's a product called ControllerMate that can do this.  See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249375/mouse-middle-click-in-mac-os-misson-control-and-close-tab-at-the-same-time-ho/249378#249378

Answer (score 1):

[Steermouse](http://www.plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) is another way to enjoy this functionality.